# Does aws-amplify work in china? Can users in China access aws-amplify set up in european server

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-amplify

Does aws-amplify work in china? Can users in China access aws-amplify set up in european server. I looked at AWS page but couldn't find the information.

Answer (score 0):

The Amplify CLI and Amplify JS help you provision AWS resources and access them from your application.  Therefore access depends on the availability of the resources themselves (i.e. Cloud Formation, S3, etc), not Amplify specifically.